# Help in understanding this bash file

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to understand the code in this page: https://github.com/corroded/git-achievements/blob/gh-pages/git-achievements

and I'm kinda at a loss on how it actually works. I do know some bash and shell scripting, but how does this script actually "store" how many times you've used a command(im guessing saving into a text file?) and how does it "sense" that you actually typed in a git command? I have a feeling it's line 464 onwards that does it but I don't seem to quite follow the logic.

Can anyone explain this in a bit more understandable context?

I plan to do some achievements for other commands and I hope to have an idea on HOW to go about it without randomly copying and pasting stuff and voodoo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes on 464 start the script, everything before are helping functions. I dont know how it gets installed, but I would assume you have to call this script instead of the normal git-command. It just checks if the first parameter is achievement, and if not then just (regular) git with the rest parameters is executed. Afterwards he checks if an error happend (if he exits). And then he just makes log_action and check_for_achievments. log_action just writes the issued command with a date into a text file, while achievments scans for that log file for certains events. If you want to add another achievment you have to do it in this check_for_achievments.
Just look how the big case handles it (most of the achievments call the count_function which counts the # usages of the function and matches when a power of 2 is reached).

Comment: actually if you look at the installation you have to alias something so you dont have to do a special command.

Comment: looking at my bash profile, it does take over my git command: i have an alias of: alias git="git-achievements"

Comment: I guess you alias git=name_of_this_script. When you call git he calls instead this script. And this script (ignoring the alias) in return calls the real git to execute the entered command. It acts as a wrapper to the normal git - thats how he records all git commands (as mentioned after executing them he writes them into dot-file and checks for the achievments)

Comment: one more thing, how does he "look" for this file when calling git-achievements? does this mean i can move this script anywhere and it will still call git-achievements correctly?

Comment: @corroded: as long as the alias is set to it, its ok to move it anywhere. If you have placed in your PATH, you dont have to set the alias to something else. But if you move it to /somewhere/else/very/unusual/bin then you have to set it new with alias=/somewhere/else/very/unusal/bin/git-achievments

Comment: ah i see i see, it seems i also set it in my path. thanks again!